# What is meant by "lateral connection" in the context of neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

A class of CNN is popular due to the implementation of residual connections.

We can use both terms "residual connections" and "skip connections" interchangeably [as they refer to the same.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/321112/42883)

> Residual connections are the same thing as 'skip connections'. They
> are used to allow gradients to flow through a network directly,
> without passing through non-linear activation functions. Non-linear
> activation functions, by nature of being non-linear, cause the
> gradients to explode or vanish (depending on the weights).

While studying some models that are used in codes of some deep learning projects, I came across the word "lateral connections".

I guess that lateral connections stand for the connections that are not present in the traditional feed-forward neural networks of any kind. Lateral connections may be from any layer to any other layer.

Am I true? If not, when can I call a connection lateral?

Comment: When you say "While studying some models that are used in codes of some deep learning projects", it may be a good idea to provide the source where you read about this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lateral connection in NN simply means that units in a hidden layer are connected with one another. Suppose we have a hidden layer Hi which has 10 from (1,2,....10) then lateral connection implies that unit 1 may be connected to unit 2.

So now the activation of unit 2 is not only dependent on incoming inputs but also on unit 1. The weight assigned to a connection between unit 2 and unit 1 needs to be learned as part of backprop.

Please refer to the below image for more details :

[image]

> Lateral connections in a feed-forward architecture. Inputs and hidden layer neurons are fully connected as are hidden layer and output layer neurons. Neuron j in the hidden layer also receives the net input of neuron (j - 1) in the hidden layer through a lateral connection

Ref: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-lateral-connections-in-feed-forward-neural-Kothari-Agyepong/167d7c20dcf37fba0388b0365d9bd42ba8b2ecde/figure/0

**Lateral Connection can occur between units in layers and can be applied to feed forward network**